# XPath : Excluding elements that have a specific attribute, and a prefix

Tags: xml, xpath

If I have a line of XML like this:

```
<type cms:tstatus="Released" cms:tmatch="element1">GUIDE DE L'UTILISATEUR</type>
```

And I want to extract all elements APART from those that contain **cms:tstatus="Released"**

Then why does this not work?

```
//*[not(@cms:tstatus="Released")]
```

I'm sure it either has something to do with the prefix... or the parsing software in place has a bug.  Can anyone help me confirm this should work or help me understand why it won't?

Comment: have you tried `//*[@cms:tstatus!="Released"]`?

Comment: Yes, and this returns everything in the same way my example does.  Ignoring the exclusion altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. Both rules are correct. But the parsing software I am using requires another rule //* to not extract anything as it seems to consider the rules above as an OR scenario. So extracts everything unless I tell it don't extract anything first, and then apply the rule. Thank you for your help. Consider this closed.

Comment: If you consider the question resolved, you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark. That marks it as resolved. Can you also let us know what parsing software has this odd behavior that you're referring to?